# Get Test EXT2 IMG file

Tags: testing, ext2

I have a task for university to deal with EXT2 file recovery. The problem is that the example drives (as IMG files) we got only contain one block group. I want to test if I read the drive correctly so I need more than one block group.

I tried to create an IMG file from my Kubuntu USB drive but did not manage to do it. I searched online but found not a single IMG file to download. Google only wanted to sell some ext2 drivers to me.

Where can I get an ext2 IMG file from?

Comment: This is a question you should ask your professor/TA. Most certainly all you need is contained in the given image. By thinking "outside the box" you are likely to approach the task in a way that is unnecessary cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about block groups, but if I wanted an `ext2` image I would first create an image file:

`fallocate --length 1G test.img`

This will create the file `test.img` in the current directory and uses the `--length` option to specify the image should be 1 gigabyte in size.

Then, create an `ext2` filesystem onto the image:

`mkfs.ext2` ./test.img

Now, you have an `ext2` image you can mount and manipulate:

`mount ./test.img /mnt/img`

Comment: fallocate did not work for me, but I used this command. For some reason I was not able to create a file bigger than 128MB. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/d/image.img count=128 bs=1M`